# How can I get from Gatwick to Heathrow by bus?

Tags: airport-transfer, buses, transportation, lhr, lgw

Is there a direct bus connection betwee Gatwick Airport to London Heathrow?

Answer (score 9):

So much rep for a copy paste job, thanks!

> **Gatwick to Heathrow:**
>
> Gatwick Express trains to London Victoria depart every 15 minutes from
>   South Terminal and take 30 minutes. The Heathrow Express service
>   departs from Paddington every 15 minutes. Terminal 4 passengers should
>   change at Heathrow Central.
>
> Heathrow Connect services operate between the same stations, but run
>   half hourly and are a slower, stopping service.
>
> Passengers can also travel to and from Heathrow and the centre of
>   London on the Piccadilly line tube.
>
> You can travel between Victoria and Paddington stations by bus, taxi
>   or London Underground (District and Circle Lines).
>
> **By bus and coach**
>
> National Express and Megabus operate non-stop services between Gatwick
>   and Heathrow, and National Express have some direct services to
>   Stansted and Luton airports. Approximate journey times are as follows:
>   •Gatwick to Heathrow - around 75 minutes •Gatwick to Stansted - around
>   3 hours •Gatwick to Luton - around 2 hours 30 minutes for direct
>   services
>
> You can buy tickets from National Express ticket desks in both
>   terminals, from the coach driver or in advance by booking online or
>   calling +44 (0)871 781 8181.

Source: **[Gatwick Airport](http://www.gatwickairport.com/to-and-from/gatwick-to-london/to-other-airports/)**

> **Heathrow – Gatwick**
>
> Approximate distance by road: 42 miles / 68km
>
> **Coach**
>
> National Express coaches run direct between Heathrow and Gatwick up to
>   six times an hour. •Journey time: 65 minutes •Cost: From £25 •Tickets
>   and information: 0871 781 8181 or NationalExpress.com
>
> megabus.com coaches run direct between Heathrow and Gatwick with
>   departures up to every hour. •Journey time: 75 minutes •Cost: from £1*
>   •Tickets and information: megabus.com or 0900 1600 900**
>
> *50p booking fee applies
>
> **Open 7 days a week, 7am - 10pm. Calls to this number are operated by JourneyCall Ltd and will cost 65p per minute, plus telephone access
>   charges.
>
> **Train**
>
> Gatwick Express trains run non-stop between London Victoria and
>   Gatwick Airport. The journey takes 30 minutes and a standard-class
>   single costs £17.70.
>
> To make the link with Heathrow your options include: •Heathrow Express
>   between Heathrow and London Paddington, Underground between Paddington
>   and Victoria (45min, £27) •London Underground between Victoria and
>   Heathrow (50min, £4.80)
>
> There’s an alternative route via Clapham Junction and Feltham (linked
>   to Heathrow by bus route 285) but it’s only really viable if you have
>   an Oyster card or UK contactless bank card for the bus leg (no cash
>   fares). Journey time: 90min–2hr. Cost (with Oyster): £27

Source: **[Heathrow Airport](http://www.heathrow.com/transport-and-directions/travel-between-airports)**

Comment: Gatwick express is costlier than normal trains to Victoria from Gatwick and doen't guarantee your arrival will be earlier than normal trains. Many travellers fall for the costly service assuming they will arrive early.

Comment: Given some of the options described here, it's probably worth mentioning that an Uber from Heathrow to Gatwick costs £51 - £64 (according to the fare estimator). You can hit the break even or money saving point with just 2 - 3 travelers depending on what your alternative is. I live near-ish Heathrow and almost always take an Uber to Gatwick when I'm traveling with someone because its far more convenient and around the same cost, unless I'm expecting heavy traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You do not state why you wish to travel by bus rather than train.

The main advantage of the bus is that you put your luggage on at one airport and take it off at the other so giving you minimal hassle. You need to bear in mind though that the traffic conditions round London, expecially between 0700 to 1000 and 1600 to 1900, can be difficult and the bus may take longer than advertised.

To add to @HankyPanky's answer there is another budget option. Take the Thameslink service from Gatwick, usually with destination Bedford, and change at King's Cross/St Pancras onto the Piccadilly line direct to Heathrow. The fare for the rail part is about GBP 11 which is much cheaper than the Gatwick Express. Bear in mind here though that the rush hour on the Piccadilly line will not be too pleasant with heavy luggage.